# Value conversions in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to round off this query result

```
'$'+CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(money, Amount ) , 1) as Amount
```

I need to convert this column to money

```
cast(round([YearlyProfit]-[MonthlyProfit],0)as int), 
cast(round(isnull(sum(SalesProfit]),0),0) as int
```

I tried a lot and couldn't do the conversion. Please suggest me.

My Try so far:

```
select left(convert(varchar(20),[YearlyProfit]-[MonthlyProfit],1),charindex('.',convert‌​(varchar(20),[YearlyProfit]-[MonthlyProfit],1)) -1)
```

Comment: what error did you get? What was expected output vs the output you got?

Comment: 1st Query - I need to round the value. 2nd Query - My expected output is like the column value should be displayed like 10,000, but now my column value is like 10000. I am confused applying the conversions.

Comment: you are casting it as `INT` why would it be displayed as `MONEY`

Comment: if I give money then the value comes up like this 10000.00 and the comma does not appear either. But I need to eliminate .00

Comment: That is a culture issue. The money data will be displayed according to the configured `COLLATION`

Comment: Even though how can  I achieve the result. Any hints to oversome this?

Comment: Trying to format strings in SQL is a code smell. Are you sure this needs to be done with SQL--or is it better handled by the client program?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display `10000.00` as `10,000` you can use the following

```
DECLARE @mymoney MONEY = '$1000000000.00'

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @mymoney, 1), CHARINDEX('.', CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @mymoney, 1)) - 1)
```

First step `convert` money to `varchar` with commas and period. than using `LEFT` only take what comes before `'.'`

Comment: I don't see the columns getting displayed since my column now has a round off value like this 10000